# I feel undeserving of jannah and Allah's forgiveness

Tags: jannah

I know that Allah is forgiving and I know that he will forgive me for my mistakes. I just can't ever seem to forgive myself I feel like a failure to Allah and no matter what I do I feel that I don't deserve jannah or Allah's forgiveness I feel so guilty all the time for small mistakes. I always try to do my best to be a good Muslim but no matter how much good things I do I feel that I could never deserve jannah or Allah. how can I get over this way of thinking and feeling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your guilt feeling only shows your Thaqwa (God consciousness)

> Anas reported God’s messenger as saying, "All the sons of Adam are
> sinners, but the best of sinners are those who are given to
> repentance."
> https://sunnah.com/mishkat:2341 (hadees is only hasan)

Sins doesn't have to be explicit sins mentioned in Quran and sunnah like theft, adultary etc, it can also be like we forget doing proper worship of Allah. The blessing of Allah to us cannot be determined

> If you tried to count Allah’s blessings, you would never be able to
> number them. Surely Allah is All-Forgiving, Most Merciful. [Quran 16:18](https://quran.com/en/an-nahl/18)

So how much worship we do do it is always less but Allah is forgiving and merciful. So don't lose heart in Allah's mercy and worship Allah to the best of your ability.

> Say, ˹O Prophet, that Allah says,˺ “O My servants who have exceeded
> the limits against their souls! Do not lose hope in Allah’s mercy, for
> Allah certainly forgives all sins. He is indeed the All-Forgiving,
> Most Merciful. َ [Quran 39:53](https://quran.com/en/az-zumar/53)

Answer (score 0):

You are undeserving of it. Allah doesn't owe you anything for your deeds as He owns you, He has the right to account you for your sins.

This is precisely why we ask Allah to accept our good deeds and forgive us our sins and grant us a high rank in paradise out of His mercy and favor.